# error 400 from 'rest-client' gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rest-client

I have a very simple ruby script which I invoke from a crontab entry, the entire script is below:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

valve_id, gpio_pin, cmd, http_host = ARGV

# puts "valve_id --> #{valve_id},  cmd --> #{cmd}, http_host --> #{http_host}"

RestClient.put "http://#{http_host}/api/valves/#{valve_id}.json", { "params" => {"cmd" => "#{cmd}"}}.to_json , :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

Here is the crontab entry:

```
ruby /home/kenb/development/CoffeeWater/lib/tasks/rest_client.rb  5 23  0 stargate:9292
```

The resource being accessed is a simple rails model, Valve, with an integer attribute 'cmd'.

I just can't seem to get the encoding right, I keep getting error 400.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code , everything works fine with my own url `http://zoker.sinaapp.com/sonar.php`

I think there is something wrong with your api interface, maybe you should cache the error message with `begin...rescue` to see what happened with your api

here is my test with your code

`ruby.rb`

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

valve_id, gpio_pin, cmd, http_host = ARGV

# puts "valve_id --> #{valve_id},  cmd --> #{cmd}, http_host --> #{http_host}"
begin
  RestClient.put "http://zoker.sinaapp.com/sonar.php", { "params" => {"cmd" => "#{cmd}","valve_id"=>"#{valve_id}","http_host"=>"#{http_host}"}}.to_json , :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
rescue => e
  puts e
end
```

run it with `ruby ruby.rb 5 23  0 stargate:9292`

here is what my api got

```
{"params":{"cmd":"0","valve_id":"5","http_host":"stargate:9292"}}---------X-Forwarded-For: 112.97.38.29, 112.97.38.29------------------Host: zoker.sinaapp.com------------------AppName: zoker------------------AppVersion: 1------------------AccessKey: loy5m01zk1------------------AppHash: 132------------------MysqlPort: 3321------------------AppCookie: default_version=1;debug=1;------------------AppSrvc: 0000000000000000------------------Connection: close------------------Content-Length: 65------------------Accept: application/json------------------Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate------------------Content-Type: application/json------------------User-Agent: Ruby---------
```

you can see the result [here](http://zoker.sinaapp.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Could you explain where I might put the begin...rescue clause and what I might look for?  The rest-client request doesn't get to my valve_controller.rb file on the server.  The only variation on the rails standard is that I have added "/api" in front of the default routes, as done in RailsCast EPISODE #323 Backbone on Rails Part 1.  I don't see the need for that, but followed the demo...

Comment: i have updated my code , you should put the `e` error trace to see what happened, I think the problem is in your `api` , not the given code.

Comment: I added the begin ... rescue and got "400 Bad Request".  Not very instructive. I can get to the rails server from my backbone-based browser client, but not from the small ruby script.

Comment: can you post the request log on the rails server to see what happened with your api?

Comment: Here is 'development.log' from rails:

Comment: The post of the development.log was too long for a comment, so I posted it as an answer, see below.

Comment: do you have a filter in your controller?i think you need post your `valves_controller.rb` to see more :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the development.log:

Started PUT "/valves/1.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-29 12:06:18 -0700
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by ValvesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"params"=>{"id"=>"1", "cmd"=>"0"}, "id"=>"1", "valve"=>{}}
  [1m[35mValve Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "valves".* FROM "valves" WHERE "valves"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mWaterManager Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "water_managers".* FROM "water_managers"  ORDER BY "water_managers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
Completed 400 Bad Request in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: valve:
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in `require'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in`block in run'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'

The mystery is the param 'valve', that is the name of the model.  Here is the modified ruby script that produced this response:

```
#
# a REST client, used to put valve updates into the server.  This script is intended to be invoked from a crontab operation
# invoked as:
# ruby /home/kenb/development/CoffeeWater/tasks/rest_client.rb valve_id gpio_pin cmd http_host
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

valve_id, gpio_pin, cmd, http_host = ARGV

begin
  RestClient.put "http://#{http_host}/valves/#{valve_id}.json", { "params" => { "id" => "#{valve_id}", "cmd" => "#{cmd}"}}.to_json , :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
rescue => e
  puts e
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved.  I had added an outer hash, :params => {...}, and this caused rest-client to throw in an extra parameter 'valve - {}', which the rails server did not like.

I don't know why.  The rails model being accessed is 'valves', and there is no reference to valve in the rest-client request.

Anyway, removing the outer param hash fixed my problem.